# radio buttons and php

Tags: php

and thanks in advance for offering your time for reading this.
I am newbie with PHP and i am doing a project for the university. 
Until now for adding boolean values i have used checkboxes. For example in my db i have a boolean record called DB_FOR_SALE that i am updating using this piece of code...

HTML part
     `<input type="checkbox" name="DB_FOR_SALE" value="1"<#DB_FOR_SALE#>>For`>For Sale

PHP part

```
    /* Update of a Record  */
    if($_REQUEST['DB_ID'] != '')
    {
    $objectid = $_REQUEST['DB_ID'];
    $upd = "update " . G_DB_PREFIX . "OBJECTS set DB_FOR_SALE='" . $_REQUEST['DB_FOR_SALE'] . "' where DB_ID='" . $_REQUEST['DB_ID'] . "'";
    $gupd = $conn->update($upd, G_NORMDB);
```

In the same way i can enter the value if the object is inserted for the first time.

How can i use that in the radio buttons case, since they have the same name.

Thanx for reading this!!

Comment: Let me just clarify, do you want your checkbox field and radio button group to have the same name under one form?

Comment: What i want is two have two radio button each corresponding to the option for_sale, for_rent..for_sale and for_rent are two boolean records in my db. They have to have the same name because you can choose either the one or the other. I dont know how to instruct the program to understand which of the two is selected and update the corresponding record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <form method="POST" action="someaction.php">
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> For Rent<br>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" checked> For Sale<br>
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
   <body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
Selection:
  <?php
    echo $_POST['group1'] == 1 ? "For Rent" : "For Sale";
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanx for your advice  Jeune but the problem is that both my values are boolean so they both must be set to 1. That where i am stacked.

Comment: You can always think of it this way: If a something is for rent then it is 1, if it is not for rent(in boolean !RENT) meaning it is for sale then it is 0. what do you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute of the selected radio button will be submitted as the value for the set with the give `name`.

Comment: Probably i havent been clear. I have two record DB_FOR_SALE and DB_FOR_RENT (both boolean) how can i instruct the program two change the value of the selected radio button?

Comment: Check the value. If it's one value then set one on and the other off, otherwise do the opposite.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking the same thing but i didnt manage to do that..Any ideas?